# Load Video From URL in Quartz Composer Visualizer

Tags: quartz-composer

I'm attempting to make a quartz composer composition that takes streaming video input from 16 different networked video cameras and outputs this video on a grid of 16 attached displays.

I'm attempting to do this in Quartz Composer and QC Visualizer with a dedicated processing composition that essentially has 16 movie importer patches with published outputs and a rendering composition with 16 bilboards arranged in a grid (where the bilboards are attached to the movie importers). This works correctly when I use local videos in the movie importers, however, whenever I try to load streamed videos (which are QT videos), QC Visualizer crashes when I try to run the compositions.

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or any other way I can accomplish my goal?

Thanks.